# When using gdb to debug program, Is there any command output file descriptor information?

Tags: debugging, gdb

When I use gdb to debug a program, I want to look the file descriptor information about the debugging progress. I use "info file", "info proc" commands, but these command outputs don't include file descriptor information. So Is there any command output file descriptor information when using gdb？ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any command output file descriptor information when using gdb？

This is OS-dependenent.

On Linux, `ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/` is often helpful.

GDB itself doesn't track the inferior process's file descriptors.

Comment: Yes, I know some commands(such as lsof) can get file descriptor information. Your answer" GDB itself doesn't track the inferior process's file descriptors." is useful to me. Thanks!